# State restoration in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, state-restoration

I am trying to use state restoration in my app, but for some reason I cannot get it to work. I have the restoration ID set in all view controllers, navigation controllers, and tab bar controllers. I have opted in using the following functions in `AppDelegate`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreSecureApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldSaveSecureApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

After killing the app on simulator and on a device, it does not restore any states. I am not receiving any warnings, am I missing something?

Comment: To test on simulator you hit stop in Xcode I think. I have not tested in a while

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm currently struggling with the same problem.

Comment: Nope, the whole thing was changed when iOS switched to Scene Delegates, I still haven't found anything that works

Comment: If you do find a decent article or video, can you perhaps link it in the post or comments, I am also deeply confused on how to implement this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll post an answer to this question if I ever find some thing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [implementing state restoration in iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64070227/implementing-state-restoration-in-ios-14)

Answer (score 0):

In order to test state restoration on the simulator you need to start your app, go back to the home screen and then press stop in Xcode with the app now in the background. Then when you launch it again, its state will get restored.